# POST json dictionary

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, post, dictionary

I'm trying the following : A model with a dictionary inside send it on the first ajax request then take the result serialize it again and send it back to the controller.

This should test that I can get back a dictionary in my model. It doesn't work

Here's my simple test:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index (T a)
    {
      return View();
    }

    public JsonResult A(T t)
    {
      if (t.Name.IsEmpty())
      {
        t = new T();
        t.Name = "myname";
        t.D = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        t.D.Add("a", "a");
        t.D.Add("b", "b");
        t.D.Add("c", "c");
      }
      return Json(t);
    }
}

//model
public class T
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IDictionary<string,string> D { get; set; }
}
```

The javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var o = {
        Name: 'somename',
        "D": {
            "a": "b",
            "b": "c",
            "c": "d"
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl('/home/a'),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl('/home/a'),
                data: JSON.stringify(result),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In firebug the json received and the json sent are identical. I can only assume something gets lost on the way.

Anyone has an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting JSON Data to ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164114/posting-json-data-to-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Due to the way [JsonValueProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx) is implemented binding dictionaries is not supported.

Comment: Care to elaborate more on that ? I mean it just reads the input stream and passes it to the JavascriptSerializer. Does it do anything else weird ?

Comment: @sirrocco, it does more than this. Look at the `JsonValueProviderFactory` with reflector. You will see that it uses the `DeserializeObject` method instead of `Deserialize` because at that moment it doesn't know the type of the model. Then it builds a completely new `DictionaryValueProvider` and as you can see only the `MakePropertyKey` and `MakeArrayKey` private functions are implemented which generate the `prefix.propertyName` and `prefix[index]` notation. There is nothing that handles the case of a dictionary which need to be of the form `prefix[index].Key` and `prefix[index].Value`.

Comment: So think of it as a bug or an unimplemented feature. As you prefer :-)

Comment: Aah yes, I see your point now. I would call this a bug :). Thanks

Comment: Bug posted (by someone else) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636647/make-jsonvalueproviderfactory-work-with-dictionary-types-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Worth noting that the above bug is now reported as FIXED at MS Connect. Yay for that.

Comment: And confirmed - if you upgrade to ASP.Net 4.5 and MVC 4 you can serialize JSON Dictionaries on POST via the default ValueBinders in MVC.

Comment: Has anyone tried to model bind to a Dictionary<string, string> am using MVC5 and it doesn't work on my controller

Comment: @Luiso I am facing the same problem. A dictionary nested within a class property is not being deserialized. Any news on this topic?

Comment: after a while i realized that the issue was that on my json i had a colon after the last `<key, value>` pair, something like this `{"data": "value",}` which is invalid json btw. Once I fixed that it worked just fine. Hope this helps

Answer (score 22):

An unfortunate workaround:

```
data.dictionary = {
    'A': 'a',
    'B': 'b'
};

data.dictionary = JSON.stringify(data.dictionary);

. . .

postJson('/mvcDictionaryTest', data, function(r) {
    debugger;
}, function(a,b,c) {
    debugger;
});
```

postJSON js lib function (uses jQuery):

```
function postJson(url, data, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
}
```

The ViewModel object being posted (presumably has a lot more going on than a dictionary):

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    . . .
    //public Dictionary<string, string> dictionary { get; set; }
    public string dictionary { get; set; }
    . . .
}
```

The Controller method being posted to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel model)
{
    var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(model.dictionary);

    // Do something with the dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 straight out of the box I'm doing this:

jSON:

```
{
    "Name": "somename",
    "D": {
        "a": "b",
        "b": "c",
        "c": "d"
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
{
}
```

This is what shows up when it comes through (Name and D are the keys):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue today and came up with a solution which doesn't require anything but registering a new model binder. It's a bit hacky but hopefully it helps someone.

```
    public class DictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Binds the model to a value by using the specified controller context and binding context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The bound value.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param><param name="bindingContext">The binding context.</param>
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

            string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
            // Create a dictionary to hold the results
            IDictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // The ValueProvider property is of type IValueProvider, but it typically holds an object of type ValueProviderCollect
            // which is a collection of all the registered value providers.
            var providers = bindingContext.ValueProvider as ValueProviderCollection;
            if (providers != null)
            {
                // The DictionaryValueProvider is the once which contains the json values; unfortunately the ChildActionValueProvider and
                // RouteDataValueProvider extend DictionaryValueProvider too, so we have to get the provider which contains the 
                // modelName as a key. 
                var dictionaryValueProvider = providers
                    .OfType<DictionaryValueProvider<object>>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(vp => vp.ContainsPrefix(modelName));
                if (dictionaryValueProvider != null)
                {
                    // There's no public property for getting the collection of keys in a value provider. There is however
                    // a private field we can access with a bit of reflection.
                    var prefixsFieldInfo = dictionaryValueProvider.GetType().GetField("_prefixes",
                                                                                      BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                                      BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    if (prefixsFieldInfo != null)
                    {
                        var prefixes = prefixsFieldInfo.GetValue(dictionaryValueProvider) as HashSet<string>;
                        if (prefixes != null)
                        {
                            // Find all the keys which start with the model name. If the model name is model.DictionaryProperty; 
                            // the keys we're looking for are model.DictionaryProperty.KeyName.
                            var keys = prefixes.Where(p => p.StartsWith(modelName + "."));
                            foreach (var key in keys)
                            {
                                // With each key, we can extract the value from the value provider. When adding to the dictionary we want to strip
                                // out the modelName prefix. (+1 for the extra '.')
                                result.Add(key.Substring(modelName.Length + 1), bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).AttemptedValue);
                            }
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The binder is registered in the Global.asax file under application_start

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Dictionary<string,string>), new DictionaryModelBinder());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution.  This worked for me when the other solutions posted here didn't.

Comment: Used this code pretty much verbatim (needed a Dictionary<string, object> instead) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with a custom model binder, and changing the way the data is sent; without using Stringify and setting the contenttype.

JavaScript:

```
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/a',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/home/a',
                    data: result,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(result) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Custom model binder:

```
public class DictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
{          
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        IDictionary<string, string> formDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Regex dictionaryRegex = new Regex(modelName + @"\[(?<key>.+?)\]", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        foreach (var key in controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith(modelName + "[")))
        {
            Match m = dictionaryRegex.Match(key);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                formDictionary[m.Groups["key"].Value] = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[key];
            }
        }
        return formDictionary;
    }
}
```

And by adding the model binder in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(IDictionary<string, string>)] = new DictionaryModelBinder();
```

Answer (score 2):

Grab the following [**NuGet**](http://www.nuget.org/) package for `System.Json`, which includes the new `JsonValue` type. `JsonValue` is a flexible new JSON representative type that fully supports C# 4 dynamic, and is also an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>>` in the event you wish to treat a payload as a dictionary/associative array.

You can pick up [System.Json (Beta) with NuGet here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json). It seems `System.Json` will be included natively in .NET 4.5, as indicated by the [documentation pages here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You might also want to read the following article to assist in getting JSON HTTP bodies to properly deserialize into JsonValue objects in your Action method parameters:

[JSON, ASP.NET MVC and JQuery - Working with Untyped JSON made easy](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-json-jquery.html)

The two relevant pieces of code from the article above would be the DynamicJsonBinder and DynamicJsonAttribute, replicated here for posterity:

```
public class DynamicJsonBinder : IModelBinder  
{  
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)  
    { 
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith  
              ("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))  
        {  
            // not JSON request  
            return null;  
        }  

        var inpStream = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;  
        inpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);  
        string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();  
        reader.Close();  


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))  
        {  
            // no JSON data  
            return null;  
        }  

        return JsonValue.Parse(bodyText);  
    }  
} 

public class DynamicJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new DynamicJsonBinder();
    }
}
```

A relevant sample use case would be:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index (T a)
    {
      return View();
    }

    public JsonResult A([DynamicJson] JsonValue value)
    {
      dynamic t = value.AsDynamic();

      if (t.Name.IsEmpty())
      {
        t = new // t is dynamic, so I figure just create the structure you need directly
        {
            Name = "myname",
            D = new // Associative array notation (woot!): 
            {
                a = "a",
                b = "b",
                c = "c" 
            }
        };
      }

      return Json(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a better deserializer.
That first line where I set the position is because the JsonValueProvider leaves the stream at the end. More MS JSON fail.

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);

var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreativeUploadModel>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

So somewhere in that CreativeUploadModel object graph there is a prop like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Asset> Assets { get; set; }
```

Which is deserialized from (for example):

```
"assets":{"flash":{"type":"flash","value":"http://1234.cloudfront.net/1234.swf","properties":"{\"clickTag\":\"clickTAG\"}"}
```

Newtonsoft JSON is the default JSON provider for WebAPI... so it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to similar problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Controllers
{
    public class DictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext context, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                string requestContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var arguments = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(requestContent);
                return arguments[bindingContext.ModelName];
            }
        }
    }
}

using Controllers;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ControllersTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class DictionaryModelBinderTest
    {
        private ControllerContext controllerContext;

        [Test]
        public void ReturnsDeserializedPrimitiveObjectsAndDictionaries()
        {
            string input =
@"{
    arguments: {
        simple: 1,
        complex: { a: 2, b: 3 },
        arrayOfSimple: [{ a: 4, b: 5 }],
        arrayOfComplex: [{ a: 6, b: 7 }, { a: 8, b: 9 }]},
    otherArgument: 1
}";
            SetUpRequestContent(input);

            var binder = new DictionaryModelBinder();
            var bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext();
            bindingContext.ModelName = "arguments";

            var model = (Dictionary<string, object>)binder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

            Assert.IsFalse(model.ContainsKey("otherArgument"));
            Assert.AreEqual(1, model["simple"]);
            var complex = (Dictionary<string, object>)model["complex"];
            Assert.AreEqual(2, complex["a"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, complex["b"]);
            var arrayOfSimple = (ArrayList)model["arrayOfSimple"];
            Assert.AreEqual(4, ((Dictionary<string, object>)arrayOfSimple[0])["a"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, ((Dictionary<string, object>)arrayOfSimple[0])["b"]);
            var arrayOfComplex = (ArrayList)model["arrayOfComplex"];
            var complex1 = (Dictionary<string, object>)arrayOfComplex[0];
            var complex2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)arrayOfComplex[1];
            Assert.AreEqual(6, complex1["a"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(7, complex1["b"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(8, complex2["a"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(9, complex2["b"]);
        }

        private void SetUpRequestContent(string input)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

            var controllerContextStub = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request.InputStream).Returns(stream);
            controllerContextStub.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);
            this.controllerContext = controllerContextStub.Object;
        }
    }
}

using Controllers;
using PortalApi.App_Start;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace PortalApi
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), new DictionaryModelBinder());
        }
    }
}
```

Have fun! :-P
Greetings
Łukasz Duda

Answer (score 1):

Post the complex object as a string and deserialize at the other end. There is no type-safety however for this. Here is a dictionary with string key and string array values.

js:

```
var data = { 'dictionary': JSON.stringify({'A': ['a', 'b'] }) };

$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/MyAction',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

c# controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string dictionary)
{
    var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, string[]> d = s.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(dictionary);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's coming upon this problem recently still, as long as you don't need your controller to specifically accept a dictionary, you can do the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage SomeMethod([FromBody] IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> values)
{
    Dictionary<Key, Value> dictionary = values.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x = x.Value);
}
```

Though it is a bit hacky.

Comment: Missing '>'.  should be: Dictionary<Key, Value> dictionary = values.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will stumble upon this thread in 2023+ because it is the FIRST answer in Google - it works now out of a box (using .Net 8.0) even with Dictionary inside Dictionary.

Controller code:

```
    public IActionResult TestModelParsing( Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>> ajaxData )
    {
        return Json( new {} );
    }
```

Javascript:

```
let data = {
    ajaxData: {
        "fieldName1": {
            innerField1: 1,
            innerField2: 2
        },
        "fieldName2": {
            innerField1: 1,
            innerField2: 2
        }
    }
}

$.ajax( {
    url: "/test/TestModelParsing",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    method : "POST",
    timeout: 600000
} );
```

[image]