# jQuery Ajax/ASP.NET MVC JsonResult using dynamics, how do I access the JSON keys?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, dynamic

Here's the JSON string returned from my action:

```
[{"Key":"Likes","Value":1},{"Key":"Loves","Value":0},{"Key":"Dislikes","Value":0},{"Key":"Message","Value":"Your vote has been changed"}]
```

Here's how I'm trying to access them:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/voteUrl',
    data: { id : '37', vote : $(this).attr('id') },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        $('#like').text(result.Likes);
        $('#love').text(result.Loves);
        $('#dislike').text(result.Dislikes);
    }
});
```

There are span tags with id's "Like", "Love", and "Dislike." On the action, there is a dynamic result, with properties like so:

```
results.Likes = 1;
results.Loves = 0;
results.Dislikes = 0;
results.Message = "Your vote has been changed";
```

But the span tags aren't being updated with the correct values. The ajax call is working, FireBug shows the JSON string is returned, and I believe I'm trying to access the keys correctly, results.PropertyName. What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array, so to show all, you have to use `for` loop. Also in your current code, you are not accessing array by key. The correct code could be:

```
success: function(result) {
 for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        $('#like').text(result[0].Value); //got likes in first iteration
        ...
}
```

or if you have fixed length, than get the value directly instead of forloop or by comparing the key if you want to use `for` loop

Comment: +1. To the OP: the problem is that ASP.NET MVC doesn't serialize dictionaries correctly, giving you this array of {Key, Value} objects instead of what you expect. There's some more detail in questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710729/post-json-dictionary-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this

```
success: function(data) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){    
        results[data[i]["Key"]] = data[i]["Value"];
    }
    $('#like').text(result.Likes);
    $('#love').text(result.Loves);
    $('#dislike').text(result.Dislikes);
}
```