# Getting null from ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand why in my controller's action I get null as string:

Here is ajax call:

```
var dict = { "A": "fake1", "B": "fake2" };
var data = { "dictionary": JSON.stringify(dict) };

$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

And action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod( string dictionary )
{
    Dictionary<string, string> usersToNotify = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>( dictionary );
    //...
}
```

Comment: Not sure about asp, but you may need parenthesis around the `new JavaScriptSerializer()` before trying to access from it

Comment: I wouldn't stringify `dict` in the `data` object. Just add `dict` to `data` and then stringify the whole lot.

Comment: Why not just have a model with `string A` and `string B` and post back to the model? - `data: { "A": "fake1", "B": "fake2" }` and delete the `contentType` option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST json dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710729/post-json-dictionary)

Comment: Could you just test to change in the ajax call the `data: JSON.stringify(data),` to  `data: data,` because you don´t need to stringify the param object name

Comment: I am just tried your code it works fine. I think you need to correct url or check for other misprints.

Comment: @Andy, I tried and again got null as parameter.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I don't want model for the simplest thing.

Comment: @Jose Rocha, I tried and it didn't even come into my method.

Comment: @Sam Zakhezin, url isn't wrong, I put breakpoint at first line of method and see that the parameter is null. No idea how it works for you.

Comment: Adding this worked for me: dataType: "text".

Comment: Then just make your method `public ActionResult MyMethod(string A, string B)` And why on earth are you writing twice as much code as necessary and than claim that you dont want to create a model (which would still be less code than you have shown)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, don't be angry. :) I really don't understand why should I make my method public ActionResult MyMethod(string A, string B). It should receive dictionary with a lot of key-value pairs, not just two pairs as in this simplified example. And what is duplicate in code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
   var dict = { "A": "fake1", "B": "fake2" };
   var data = { "dictionary": JSON.stringify(dict) };

   $.ajax({
   url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
       data: {
        dictionary:data.dictionary
       },
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       dataType: 'json'
   });
```

Comment: `dictionary:JSON.stringify(dict)` instead of `dictionary:data.dictionary`

Comment: With this it doesn't find my methdod, doesn't come into it.

Comment: Do you mean that the request is not sent of what?