# Postman unable to set values to dictionary parameter for C# web api

Tags: c#, postman

I have below code written to test for reading the dictionary key and values from Postman.

C# web api method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Service/testdictionary",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void testdictionary(Dictionary<string,object> data)
{
if(data != null)
{
string str1 = data["a1"].ToString();
string str2 = data["a2"].ToString();
string str3 = data["a3"].ToString();
}
}
```

Postman input Body:(raw and JSON(application/json))

```
{
"data": {
"a1": "b1",
"a2": "b2",
"a3": "b3"
}
}
```

How am I calling the method from Postman:

[image: Postman Call]

What is the issue:
Whenever I am trying to assign dictionary object data from the postman, in C# code it is getting assigned as an empty dictionary.

What is required:
I want to read a dictionary element from postman to my API code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST json dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710729/post-json-dictionary)

Comment: Thanks for Sharing !! Solution provide by @Adriani6 is suitable for MVC. if you have something which will help me then post.

Comment: @PratikNavagekar, how to call your method? please share in the question

Comment: @Div, add the image file for postman method call.
I am trying to set dictionary in my web api from Postman call.

Comment: Are you using WCF?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes its WCF

Comment: Your dictionary is actually `data["data"]`.

Comment: @Crowcoder can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2):

Your items are not `data["a1"]`, `data["a2"]`, etc. You have a dictionary of ONE item whose key is "data", so it is `data["data"]`. Your value for that one item is an object with a1, a2 and a3 properties. Not sure what that works out to in your WCF app but in Web API it is a `JToken` from the Newtonsoft Json.Net library.

If you want a `Dictionary` with keys a1, a2, a3 you need to adjust your JSON body to exclude the "data" level:

```
{
"a1": "b1",
"a2": "b2",
"a3": "b3"
}
```

> UPDATE

If you are unable to change the JSON structure for some reason, you could create a class with a `data` property that is of Type `Dictionary<string,object>`:

```
public class TheData
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> data {get;set;}
}
```

Then your api method would take a `TheData` type instead of `Dictionary<string,object>`:

```
public void testdictionary(TheData _data)
{
    ...
```

and your code would access the dictionary like:

```
string d1 = _data.data["a1"].ToString(); // d1 == "b1"
```

Comment: Thanks for Sharing the Solution unfortunately the solution didnt work for dictionary. Not sure whether its a limitation for WCF service. But I have managed to get idea from your solution. Posting my Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

i tried! it works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace StackOverFlowProblemWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult TestDictionary([FromBody]Dictionary<string,object> data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                string string1 = data["a1"].ToString();
                string string2 = data["a2"].ToString();
                string string3 = data["a3"].ToString();

                return Ok("Data Recieved."); // When the data is successfully recieved.
            }
            else
                return BadRequest("Data is not received.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Look! did you see that: the data is received.
...

Comment: Yes, but that is not the same JSON structure that OP is sending.

Comment: He is using WCF not webapi!

Comment: @Rehan.S Yes I am using WCF and the solution provided by you works fine with MVC api's.

Comment: @Pratik Navageker... Sorry for my answer....the reason is that,i was wondering that you asking about web api  and mvc....

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my problem as a workaround, can say similar kind of dictionary.

**What's the Solution:
Use class object instead of dictionary.**

Here is My Solution:

I add a class, similar structure as dictionary I wanted.(Only thing is I have to code extra line of code to declare class with Keys , which i was avoiding earlier)

Here is my code from web api:

```
    public class mydictionary
    {
        public string a1 { get; set; }
        public string a2 { get; set; }
        public string a3 { get; set; }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Service/testdictionary",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string testdictionary(mydictionary data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            string str1 = data.a1.ToString();
            string str2 = data.a2.ToString();
            string str3 = data.a3.ToString();
            return "success".ToString();
        }
       else
        {
            return "unsuccess".ToString();
        }

    }
```

Here is my Postman input and Output:
[Postman Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ocl.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked in this format
ActionParam = [{ Key: 'orderId', Value: '200' }];
'ActionParam' is a dictionary property in a model and also tested on WCF.