# Passing an array Of Objects Into An MVC .net core Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

am using .netcore 1.1 , Visual studio 2017 , Jquery version = "3.2.1"

,am trying to make  the MVC controller to get data from my page , 
i have 2 arrays in java , one is an array of Object (model view) and one is an array of strings

1. objects array always return error 400 (bad request) 
   2- string array ,always send null to the controller

i followed the below answers with no success

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255459/6741585

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808033/6741585

below is my chtml page

```
     //#region send data back t oserver
        $('#Savebtn').click(function () {
            console.log(editedRows);

            var UpdatedRows = JSON.stringify({ 'acActivityed': editedRows });
            console.log(UpdatedRows);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/acActivity/Edit",
                //traditional: true,   
                data: UpdatedRows ,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    // here comes your response after calling the server
                    alert('Suceeded');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error : " + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
        //#endregion

        //#region deleted all selected
        $('#DeleteSelectedbtn').on('click', function () {
            if (confirm("Are you sure to delete All Selected ?????")) {
                var selectedData = [];
                 var selectedIndexes;

                    selectedIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
                    jQuery.each(selectedIndexes, function (index, value) {
                        selectedData.push(grid.getDataItem(value).id);
                    });
                    console.log(selectedData);
                    var SelectedIds = selectedData.join(',') ;
                    console.log(SelectedIds);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/acActivity/DeleteSelected",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "ids": SelectedIds }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        grid.render();
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert("error : " + err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //#endregion
```

and both do have data as below console shots
the selected ID's one 
[image: Object Array from Console]

[image: ID's Selected from Console]

my Controller 
this one should expect the list of object and always return bad request ,

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public jsonResult Edit( List<acActivitytbl> acActivityed)
    public ActionResult Edit( List<acActivitytbl> acActivityed)
    {
       foreach (acActivitytbl it in acActivityed)
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, it.ID);
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, it.Name);
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, it.IsActive);
        }


        //return View(acActivityed);
        return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "end of Page" });
    }
```

that one should expect the delimited string ,but always receive null

```
    public ActionResult DeleteSelected(string ids)
    {
        try
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ' ' };


            string[] words = ids.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (words != null && words.Length > 0)
            {

                foreach (var id in words)
                {

                    bool done = true; //new acActivitiesVM().Delete(Convert.ToInt32(id));
                    logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, " acActivities ID {0} is Deleted Scussefully  ", id);
                }
                return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Deleted Scussefully" });

            }
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Nothing Selected" });
        }
        catch (Exception dex)
        {
    ..... removed to save space 
     });
        }
    }
```

i know there is something missing here ,but i cannot find it ,any help in that ??

Comment: Its just `data: UpdatedRows,` (`UpdatedRows` is already you correct data) and you can remove `traditional: true,` (that is not applicable for collections of complex objects or your `contentType` option.

Comment: thanks ,i did that exactly and still getting same error (400 (Bad Request))

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the response (Network tab) to determine what the error is. And with the 2nd example, why are you taking an array, joining it to a `string` and then splitting it back again in the controller?)

Comment: for the 2nd one , am trying every thing ,hoping that a try may make things go better ,so i tried to send it as string in one of them ,and kept it there as is ,

Comment: In 2nd case no need to join , you can send list of string id to controller List<string> id

Comment: In 1st case 400 (bad request) mean you sending bad parameter to your controller .. Make sure are you sending all the parameter to controller ?