# Passing A List Of Objects Into An ActionResult MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

possible duplicate [Passing A List Of Objects Into An MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)

but my question is when I pass

```
var things = [
  {employee:'test',effectiveDate:'',expirationDate:'' },
  { employee:'test',effectiveDate:'',expirationDate:'' }
];

$.ajax({
 contentType: 'application/json',
 type: "POST",
 url: "/MyController/CheckMethod",
 dataType: "json",
 data: JSON.stringify(things),
 async: false,
 success: function (data) {
```

to an controller method which is a `[HTTPPOPST] JsonResult` then I'm getting `value` into my `List<MYMODEL>`

but when I take a controller method as `'ActionResult'` then i'm getting `null` in `List<MYMODEL>`

why so any thing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me in controller methods of both types `JsonResult` and `ActionResult`. Show me both the controller methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think first of all your JSON should be strongly typed. 
and once it already strongly typed you need not use JSON.stringfy. 
instead go with,

```
data: {"things" : things},
```

and your controller should be like

```
public IActionResult ActionName(List<Model> things)
```

Comment: Wrong! You cannot bind a an array of objects to a `List<T>` unless its `stringified` (and `IActionResult` is core-mvc, not mvc)

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the ajax function. Assuming your controller method is

```
public ActionResult CheckMethod(List<MYMODEL> items)
```

Then it should be

```
data: JSON.stringify('items': things),
```

not

```
data: JSON.stringify(things),
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work with both scenarios as `JsonResult` is just a type of `ActionResult` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more information).

If your action only returns `JSON` data, stick with `JsonResult`; it makes your action less error-prone as Visual Studio will let you know if you accidentally try to return another type of result. Use `ActionResult` when your action returns more than one type of result.

That being said, Stephen Muecke's observation is correct; assuming your action is expecting a `List<MYMODEL>`, you're "stringifying" your objects but are not assigning them to a variable. Make sure that the variable name you declare in the `AJAX` function has the same name as the parameter your `ActionResult` (or `JsonResult`) expects.