# How to send int array from ajax call from JS to controller action as a parameter in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have an object selectedDocTypes as [23,45,78]

I need to pass it as a parameter to my controller action.
But the value is not getting assigned to parameter, it is null.

Here is code:

JS:

```
function addNewIssue(accountSID,selectedDocTypes, callback) {
var Data = { accountSID: accountSID, selectedDocTypes: selectedDocTypes };
$.ajax(landforceAPIURL + '/AddNewIssue', {
        cache: false,
        data: Data,
        success: function (data) {
             if (callback)
                    callback(data)
                },
        error: dataContext.queryFailed
        });
};
```

C#:

```
[HttpGet, Route("AddNewIssue")]
public string AddNewIssue(string accountSID,int[] selectedDocTypes)
{...}
```

Comment: The GET should be used for getting data, you shouldn't use GET method for adding new items.

Comment: you might also need to set an extra ajax parameter traditional: true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly defined `selectedDocTypes` in JavaScript as an array, You have to specify `contentType` send to server in your ajax call, like:

```
$.ajax(landforceAPIURL + '/AddNewIssue', {
        cache: false,
        data: Data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //content type send to sever
```

Answer (score 0):

I second what @haz commented.

However for this issue, this answer seems to have it covered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255459/4349196.

Another possible solution is to use custom JavaScript to construct a URL like:

```
...accountSID=jSmith&selectedDocTypes=23&selectedDocTypes=45&selectedDocTypes=78
```

See here for a related example: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/.