# C# MVC No submit pass object between views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controllers, pass-data

I am sorry for my typos.I am working on proof of concept C# ASP.NET MVC application where I need to pass data between two views when there is no post and get. One view launches a modal dialog and I need communication between them. We are using JQuery.

I have a view called Charges.cshtml with a data grid. The first column of the datagrid may have span element or a link element depending on a 
property which will tell whether the charge have single or multiple descriptions. The view looks like below.

[image: Charges]

If the charge has multiple descriptions user will click the corresponding description link( Description2 in this case ) and a modal dialog will open showing various descriptions like below

[image: Multiple Descriptions]

Now in this modal dialog user will confirm/select one description. Now I need to close the modal dialog and update the description of selected
charge like below

[image: Updated Description]

The hard part here is how to pass data between two views. I am ok to pass data via controller or via javascript.

I tried various ways to pass selected charge from Charges.cshtml to LoadLoanChargeDescriptions method in LoanCharge controller like json serialize, ViewData, ViewBag, TempData and so on but of no use. I can pass simple data types like int, string, float but not whole object. I feel I need to pass CurrentDescription and Descriptions to my controller and from their I need to move to other pieces. I tried to pass List of strings but could not see how to access them in controller since I got count as 0 in my controller. I am able to open popup of multiple descriptions UI ( for now just added Hello text )

Please see below for my code snippets

Charges.cshtml

```
@model ChargeViewModel
@using (Html.FAFBeginForm())
{
    <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr >                   
                    //.....                     
                    <td>
                        @if(Model.IsMultipleMatch)
                        {
                            var loanCharge = Model as ChargeViewModel;
                            if (loanCharge.IsMultipleMatch == true)
                            {
                                //string vm = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loanCharge);                                                                             
                                <span>
                                    <a 
onclick="ShowMatchingDescriptions('@Url.Action("LoadLoanChargeDescriptions", "LoanCharge")','', '920','500')">
                                        @loanCharge.Description
                                    </a>
                                </span>    
                             }                        
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span>Model.Description</span>
                        }  

                    </td>
                </tr>                     
                </tbody>    
            </table>
    </div> 
}

public class ChargeViewModel
{
  public string Description {get;set;}
  public bool IsMultipleMatch {get;set;}
  public List<string> Descriptions {get;set;}
}

public class LoanChargeController
{
  public ActionResult LoadLoanChargeDescriptions()
  {
      // get data here and pass/work on
      return View("_PartialMultipleMatchPopup", null);
  }
}
```

In Review.js

```
function ShowMatchingDescriptions(popUpURL, windowProperties, w, h) {
    try {                
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

        var properties = windowProperties + "dialogwidth:" + w + "px;dialogheight:" + h + "px;dialogtop:" + top + "px;dialogleft:" + left + "px;scroll:yes;resizable:no;center:yes;title:Matching Lender’s Fee;";
        $.when(
        window.showModalDialog(popUpURL, window, properties)
        )
        .then(function (result) {
            var childWindow = result;
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error : " + err)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I updated my question and posted more details.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2**

Please see for my solution at below link.

[MVC pass model between Parent and Child Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729567/mvc-pass-model-between-parent-and-child-window)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the AJAX for pass the data?

```
    function ChargeViewModel() {
        this.Description ='';
        this.IsMultipleMatch =false;

    }

    var chargeViewModel= new ChargeViewModel();
    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'chargeViewModel': chargeViewModel });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadLoanChargeDescriptions", "LoanChargeController")',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
           //result will be your partial page html output
        },
        failure: function (response) {

        }
    });
```

Then you have to change the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult LoadLoanChargeDescriptions(ChargeViewModel chargeViewModel)
  {
      // get data here and pass/work on
      return View("_PartialMultipleMatchPopup", null);
  }
```

Let me know you have queries..

Comment: @Siva..Thank you very much for your help. Actually recently our architecture team has made changes to our framework and $.ajax throws exception thats why I need to use ShowMatchingDescriptions() in my Review.js. Can you please let me know how can I do like that

Comment: @Ziggler . Sorry.I am not familiar with Review.js

Comment: @ Siva.. I solved .. please see this for my solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729567/mvc-pass-model-between-parent-and-child-window