# Post Objects collection to Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, http-post

I am trying to make an http post using jquery to the Web API controller, I am posting an array of objects to the controller but when is gets to the server the array is empty.

javascript

```
        var url = "api/actuary/" + $("#ActuaryId").val() + "/documents/";
        var inputs = $("#proofOfTraining input[type='checkbox']");
        var courseAttended = []
        inputs.each(function (ind, val) {
            var course = {};
            course["IsDone"] = $(val).is(":checked");
            course["Title"] = $(val).attr("name");
            course["ActuaryId"] = $("#ActuaryId").val();
            courseAttended.push(course);
        });
        console.log(courseAttended)
        $.post(url, JSON.stringify({ courseAttended }), function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
```

post Data

[image]

controller

```
    [Route("api/actuary/{actuaryId:long}/documents/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> uploadCourseTrainingProofAsync(List<CourseModel> courseAttended)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Data.ADPDB db = new Data.ADPDB())
            {
                foreach (CourseModel course in courseAttended)
                {
                    var tempDoc = new documents();
                    tempDoc.ActuaryId = course.ActuaryId;
                    tempDoc.Document = null;
                    tempDoc.DocumentTypeId = -1;
                    tempDoc.Done = course.IsDone;
                    tempDoc.Title = course.Title;

                    db.documents.Add(tempDoc);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return InternalServerError(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
    public class CourseModel
{
    public int ActuaryId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can we see the array of objects you are passing, and if you are using post then why dont you pass actuaryId in the body ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ courseAttended: courseAttended })`

Comment: Try just posting JSON.stringify(courseAttended); 
This looks like you're sending an object to your controller, rather than an array.

Comment: try with JSON.stringify( courseAttended )

Comment: @Tom Johnson Whether its in an object or not I am still getting on empty array on the server.

Comment: I have tried the above suggestions but the array is still coming in empty

Comment: can you remove {actuaryId:long} from your code and try ? and one more thing try to change your ActuaryId type as string instead of int

Comment: I'm not sure if this is different from @RoryMcCrossan 's answer but try to use JSON.stringify({ 'courseAttended': courseAttended }) also try to pass the data type as JSON into the method $.post, although it should be smart to detect the type by itself.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas it's the same.

Comment: Thanks RoryMcCrossan. @TiisetsoTjabane you can check this question too it has some good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Abdullah Dibas I ended up with the same solution suggested at the post.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me.

Javascript

```
        var inputs = $("#proofOfTraining input[type='checkbox']");

        var courseAttended = []
        inputs.each(function (ind, val) {
            var course = {};
            course["IsDone"] = $(val).is(":checked");
            course["Title"] = $(val).attr("name");
            course["ActuaryId"] = parseInt($("#ActuaryId").val());
            courseAttended.push(course);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "api/actuary/" + $("#ActuaryId").val() + "/documents/",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(courseAttended),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/actuary/{actuaryId:long}/documents/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> 
    uploadCourseTrainingProofAsync(List<CourseModel> courseAttended)
    {
     //.....
    }
```

I m more interested as to why I have specify the rest of the details in the ajax request.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Most likely the original code did not specify the correct content type (JSON) so the model binder was unable to bind the incoming data to the model.

Answer (score 0):

you have specify Content-Type for your request. for your case json. Also you have to change the type of ActuaryId int to string in your model class. below is the working code.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "api/url",
        data: JSON.stringify(courseAttended),
        success:  (response)=> {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: (response) =>{
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

public class CourseModel
{
    public string ActuaryId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}
```