# Json Data Posted from View to Control return Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new at MVC programming. Currently working on VS2017. I am trying to post data from View in JSON String format to Controller. When checked at Jquery Console the data is there but at controller it is received as null.

This is my Jquery Ajax

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
            var Studentdata = { JsonStr: addStudent }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(Studentdata))
            $(this).val('Please wait...');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Students/SaveStudents',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(Studentdata),
                dataType: "JSON",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf - 8',
            }); });
```

This is the Json String which is shown on the console on Click of Save Button

```
{"JsonStr":[{"StudentId":"1","Name":"Pravin","Email":"pra@gmal.com"},{"StudentId":"2","Name":"ramesh","Email":"ram@ymail.com"},{"StudentId":"3","Name":"suresh","Email":"s@mail.com"},{"StudentId":"4","Name":"parvesh","Email":"peter@h.com"}]}
```

Below is how my controller action is:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveStudents(string JsonStr)
        {
              // conditions to be written
            return View();
        }
```

Please, help me to resolve it. I tried a lot.

Comment: Please suggest what changed should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

Step 1. Make sure that you have `Studentdata` class  in server side.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveStudents(List<Studentdata> JsonStr)
    {
          // conditions to be written
        return View();
    }
```

Step 2. Adjust format contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, as well. I see that it contains unnecessary spaces.

BTW, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255459/9071943) is very useful.

Comment: I have tried doing this also. Studentdata being a view model.

Comment: Adjust format `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` as well. I see that it contains unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Remove "traditional:true;" as well.

Comment: Give me your full code(Viewmodel, jquery, controller) after changing code.

Comment: You can add your code via compiler C# code online here: https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: It works fine for me from your code after changing, man. https://ibb.co/cX9hhT1

Comment: what changes did you make? removed traditional and extra spaces or any thing additional. As I am still not getting it, even after clear the cache. Have you added any extra references?

Comment: I got it used [FormBody] in the Controller function. It solved. Thank you Phong. The link you provided above helped to resolve it.