# What is the correct format to pass array object to Controller using JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Trying to pass an object to the model list from JQuery in following format, but they appear null in VS's debugger

```
obj.data.GoUsers = [{ Email: 'r@gmail.com', InvitationStatus: 1 }]
```

Although if I pass in following format it works, but this format doesnt look feasible to build dynamically. Any thoughts?

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.data["GoUsers[" + i + "].Email"] = "test" + i + "@g.com";
    obj.data["GoUsers[" + i + "].InvitationStatus"] = i;
 }
```

> GoUsers is the type of list of model.

```
Public Property GoUsers As List(Of GOUsersModel)
```

ajax final call

```
post(obj.url, $.param(obj.data), callback_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass in an array of objects to an MVC controller method, you need to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
obj.data.GoUsers = JSON.stringify([{ Email: 'r@gmail.com', InvitationStatus: 1 }, { Email: '123@gmail.com', InvitationStatus: 0 }]);
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding.

[Passing A List Of Objects Into An MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Rishi

Comment: I have tried using JSON.stringify but didnt work. Any thoughts ?

Comment: How about `contentType and dataType `? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255459/9071943

Comment: Tried all the options but no luck. Only thing I am uncertain if I need to pass list object as a function parameter to controller or not. For example, My ActionResult function is 

Public Function Submit(Model As ConfigModel) As ActionResult

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your solution.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.data["GoUsers"][i]["Email"] = "test" + i + "@g.com";
    obj.data["GoUsers"][i]["InvitationStatus"] = i;
}
```