# Not geting expected data from jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

Here is the c# web method

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

Here is the jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://10.0.2.2/SampleService/Service/HelloWorld.asmx",
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            timeout: 15000,
            success: function (rtndata) {
                 alert('Got Success ::'+ rtndata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
                alert("Excep:: "+exception +"Status:: "+xhr.statusText);
        }
        });
```

But instead of getting `Hello World` in `rtndata` i'm getting the full html response page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a json model or disable layout

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164114/posting-json-data-to-asp-net-mvc
Look at how that guy is using a Json model on return.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an html page is because you are sending a html page.

You should double check your code to know if anything is append to the response before send the output.

Try to send a JSON formatted response to the ajax call like:

```
{'hello':'world'}
```

Then you add dataType as an option of $.ajax. If you want to print the output, you can do alert(JSON.stringify(response)).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.0.2.2/SampleService/Service/HelloWorld.asmx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function (rtndata) {
        alert('Got Success ::' + JSON.stringify(rtndata));
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

There are an important thing... More times you add cache: false, but this does not work properly and you should do a trick to solve.

Add the timestamp as a parameter of the call like:

```
var date = new Date();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.0.2.2/SampleService/Service/HelloWorld.asmx?timestamp="+date.now(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function (rtndata) {
        alert('Got Success ::' + JSON.stringify(rtndata));
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the method name to the URL (`/HelloWorld`, for example) and specify `method: "post"` in your ajax call (if you want to use a `POST` request). Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://10.0.2.2/SampleService/Service/HelloWorld.asmx/HelloWorld",
    method:"POST",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function (rtndata) {
        alert('Got Success ::' + rtndata);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

If you want to use `GET` as the request method, make sure you have this tags in your *web.config* file:

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Also, you need to decorate the service method with the [`ScriptMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx):

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

The ajax call (`method: "GET"` is optional, as it is the default method for `text`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:57315/helloworld.asmx/HelloWorld",
    method: "GET"
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function (rtndata) {
        alert('Got Success ::' + rtndata);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

As you are using `cache: false`, probably you want to [use the `GET` request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.
It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

The html page you get is an overview of all the available webmethod in the servicer - an API of sorts. Try navigating to it in a browser.

If you want to call your Hello WebMethod you should add "/Hello" as the method name to the url:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  url: 'http://10.0.2.2/SampleService/Service/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  timeout: 15000,
  success: function (rtndata) {
     alert('Got Success ::'+ rtndata);
  },
  error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
     alert("Excep:: "+exception +"Status:: "+xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

You can read more here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/