# Use Newtonsoft for MVC input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Say I define a class as follows:

```
public class Foo {
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "custoomername")]
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I'm expecting to read/write some bad JSON. Not invalid syntax, but perhaps another developer has a spelling error I need to workaround (custoomer instead of customer).

Now, in my controller I have this method:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(Foo foo) {
   return Json(foo);
}
```

I want the input object `foo` and the returned JSON from `foo` to both use NewtonSoft and not the internal JavascriptSerializer that is default on MVC.

I was able to solve the output only so far using [this](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-make-JSON-NET-as-the-default-JSON-serializer-in-ASP-NET-MVC/4257/) example. However, the input doesn't work. I tried replacing the `ValueFactoryProvider` for the `JsonValueProviderFactory` with this [example](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/01/10/asp-net-mvc-3-improved-jsonvalueproviderfactory-using-json-net/) however that doesn't appear to understand what object type the requesting method will want.

Is it possible to do this?

[Edit:] Under the proposed duplicate's answer the `ExpandoObject` is used and a `DictionaryValueProvider` is created. This still has the bad JSON in it and does not deserialize into my class.

Comment: There are many many questions already on here about this, but yes this is possible.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That answer does not work.

Comment: we aren't saying it is a duplicate of one question we are saying that even a basic search of stack overflow yields *MANY* questions on this exact topic

Comment: None that I can find. And none that work. And yes this question is being flagged as a duplicate above. Which does not solve my issue.

Comment: I don't believe they can flag it as a duplicate of an unknown set of questions, but yes there are many questions that a very cursory search brings up on this exact topic - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4164114/594354