# How to pass multiple JSON data objects from CSHTML to WEB.API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Based on the following question: [passing-multiple-json-objects-as-data-using-jquerys-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545316/passing-multiple-json-objects-as-data-using-jquerys-ajax)

My situation is similar, however different, and I was wondering if the solution applies:

My WEB.API code section is as follows:

```
[Route("api/admin/SiteSettings/UpdateCompanyContactInformation")]
[HttpPut]
[ResponseType(typeof(SiteSettings.CompanyContactInformation))]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateCompanyContactInformation(
    SiteSettings.CompanyContactInformation _oCompanyContactInformation,
    SiteSettings.SiteDetails _oSiteDetails)
{
    SiteSettings _oSiteSettings = new SiteSettings();
    return Ok(_oSiteSettings.CompanyContactInformation_Update(_oCompanyContactInformation, _oSiteDetails));
}
```

So back to my main question do I do a multi-level JSON data object as:

```
_data={_oCompanyContactInformation: { ... }, _oSiteDetails: {...}}
```

??

Comment: Yes, the answer is the same.

Comment: getting the following error:

Comment: "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Can't bind multiple parameters ('_oCompanyContactInformation' and '_oSiteDetails') to the request's content."

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: If you're using the web api controller, the fact is that those controllers only allow one parameter. If you want to keep using those controller, you'll have to create a new class encapsulating the others. Else you can use a normal controller, then you'll have the ability to have multiple parameters.

Comment: Thank you @GregoireD. That makes perfect sense.